# How to remove single and/or double quotes from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

How would I remove double quotes from a String?

For example: I would expect ( BANK "BTB” AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ ) to produce ( BANK BTB ), without the double quote. And I want to remove the words after the last quote. The main problem is that the quotes are different. Quotes can be both " and ” . A String ( "KAPİTAL BANK" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ ) can also be.

Here's the code I've tried (payer.namesIst is a String):

```
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(""(.*?)”");
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");

        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(payer.nameIst);
        while (m1.find())
        {
            payer.nameIst = m1.group(1);          
        }
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(payer.nameIst);
        while(m2.find()) {
            payer.nameIst = m2.group(1);
        }
```

The code I wrote removed the word before the quote.
Example: ( BANK "BTB” AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ ) to BTB

Comment: You can match different types of quotation marks by listing them within a square bracket, i.e. `[\"”]`. So p2 works with the modification:
```Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(".*[\"”](.*?)[\"”].*");```

Comment: But it still deletes the word before the quotation mark.  Ex: a String is (KAPİTAL "BANK" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ).with the modification, my output is BANK, but I want KAPİTAL BANK

Comment: String inputString = "BANK \"BTB” AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ";

// Remove double quotes
String outputString = inputString.replaceAll("[\"”]", "");

// Remove any text after the last quote
int lastQuoteIndex = outputString.lastIndexOf(" ");
if (lastQuoteIndex != -1) {
    outputString = outputString.substring(0, lastQuoteIndex);
}

Comment: It returns (BANK BTB AÇIQ SƏHMDAR). But I need (BANK BTB). And I can`t fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want to remove the quotes as well as everything that follows the quoted name.

Try this:

```
    String input = "BANK \"BTB” AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ";
    String output = input.replaceAll("^([^\"”]*)[\"”]([^\"”]+)[\"”].*$", "$1$2");
    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a simple solution without regular expression satisfies you, but here it goes:

```java
public class QuotesRemover {
    
    
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       String txt = "\"KAPİTAL BANK\" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ ";
       
       System.out.println(quoteRemover(txt));
   }
   
   public static String quoteRemover(String txt) {
        int lastIndexOfDoubleQuote = txt.lastIndexOf("\"");
        int lastIndexOfQuote = txt.lastIndexOf("”");
        int lastIndexTotal = lastIndexOfDoubleQuote > lastIndexOfQuote ? 
                lastIndexOfDoubleQuote : lastIndexOfQuote;
        
        int quotesTotalQty = (int) txt.chars()
                .filter(ch -> ch == '"' || ch == '”')
                .count();
        
        String withoutQuotes = txt.replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("”", "");
        return withoutQuotes.substring(0, lastIndexTotal - quotesTotalQty + 1);
   }
}
```

it works :-) and returns `KAPİTAL BANK` as you want it.

Have a lovely day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var payer = "BANK \"BTB” AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ";

    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\b.+\\b\\s[\"”].*[\"”])");
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(payer);
    while (m2.find()) {
        payer = m2.group(1).replaceAll("[\"”]", "");
    }
    System.out.println(payer);
}
```

Here I've used the regex symbol \b as it denotes the boundary of a word and \s as a single whitespace character. Hence the regex extracts the word before the quotation as well as the quotation and its content. Using String::replaceAll, the quotations are removed.

Edit: Perhaps it fits the solution better to have a more lenient way of matching a group of anything which appears before the quotation. If so, you may change the regex to
`Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(.*[\"”].*[\"”])");`